# Android Q Edge to Edge app content not showing transparent navigation bar

Tags: android-10.0

I followed the documentation of making the [Gestural Navigation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/gesturalnav) to extend the app edge to edge. But I am not able to see the navigation bar changing into transparent.

build.gradle settings,

```
        compileSdkVersion 'android-Q'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
```

styles values,

```
<!-- Testing Edge to Edge app content -->
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

<!-- Optional, but recommended for full edge-to-edge rendering -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

I set the UI visibility flags in `onCreate()` method

```
        //        Adding UI Visibility flag for edge to edge app content
        View view = findViewById(R.id.mainView);
//        hide navigation
//        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
//        layout stable
//        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
//        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//        having two flags hide navigation or layout fullscreen
//        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
//        having two flags hide navigation or layout stable
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```